# Odoo opportunity new message uncheck recipient

Tags: javascript, python, crm, odoo, odoo-10

In Odoo when I open an opportunity from "My pipeline" and on that opportunity I press button "New message" then customer from that opportunity appears (along with followers of that oppportunity) as a receiver of that message:

there is a **checked checkbox** near the name of that customer in the list of recipients for *that message*.

This is because file `addons/mail/static/src/xml/chatter.xml` has this:

```
 <!-- List of followers -->
                <div class="o_composer_suggested_partners">
                    <t t-foreach='widget.suggested_partners' t-as='recipient'>
                        <div t-attf-title="Add as recipient and follower (reason: #{recipient.reason})">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   t-att-checked="recipient.checked ? 'checked' : undefined"
                                   t-att-data-fullname="recipient.full_name"/>
                            <t t-esc="recipient.name"/>
                            <t t-if="recipient.email_address">(<t t-esc="recipient.email_address"/>)</t>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </div>
```

And hovering on the one of the unwanted recipients shows following message *"Adds as recipient and follower (reason: Customer)"*.

There is relevant source code in `addons/crm/models/crm_lead.py`

```
@api.multi
def _message_add_suggested_recipient(self, result, partner=None, email=None, reason=''):
    """ Called by message_get_suggested_recipients, to add a suggested
        recipient in the result dictionary. The form is :
            partner_id, partner_name<partner_email> or partner_name, reason """
    self.ensure_one()
    if email and not partner:
        # get partner info from email
        partner_info = self.message_partner_info_from_emails([email])[0]
        if partner_info.get('partner_id'):
            partner = self.env['res.partner'].sudo().browse([partner_info['partner_id']])[0]
    if email and email in [val[1] for val in result[self.ids[0]]]:  # already existing email -> skip
        return result
    if partner and partner in self.message_partner_ids:  # recipient already in the followers -> skip
        return result
    if partner and partner.id in [val[0] for val in result[self.ids[0]]]:  # already existing partner ID -> skip
        return result
    if partner and partner.email:  # complete profile: id, name <email>
        result[self.ids[0]].append((partner.id, '%s<%s>' % (partner.name, partner.email), reason))
    elif partner:  # incomplete profile: id, name
        result[self.ids[0]].append((partner.id, '%s' % (partner.name), reason))
    else:  # unknown partner, we are probably managing an email address
        result[self.ids[0]].append((False, email, reason))
    return result

@api.multi
def message_get_suggested_recipients(self):
    """ Returns suggested recipients for ids. Those are a list of
    tuple (partner_id, partner_name, reason), to be managed by Chatter. """
    result = dict((res_id, []) for res_id in self.ids)
    if 'user_id' in self._fields:
        for obj in self.sudo():  # SUPERUSER because of a read on res.users that would crash otherwise
            if not obj.user_id or not obj.user_id.partner_id:
                continue
            obj._message_add_suggested_recipient(result, partner=obj.user_id.partner_id, reason=self._fields['user_id'].string)
    return result
```

and in `addons/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js`

```
message_get_suggested_recipients: function () {
    var self = this;
    var email_addresses = _.pluck(this.suggested_partners, 'email_address');
    return this.thread_dataset
        .call('message_get_suggested_recipients', [[this.context.default_res_id], this.context])
        .done(function (suggested_recipients) {
            var thread_recipients = suggested_recipients[self.context.default_res_id];
            _.each(thread_recipients, function (recipient) {
                var parsed_email = utils.parse_email(recipient[1]);
                if (_.indexOf(email_addresses, parsed_email[1]) === -1) {
                    self.suggested_partners.push({
                        checked: true,
                        partner_id: recipient[0],
                        full_name: recipient[1],
                        name: parsed_email[0],
                        email_address: parsed_email[1],
                        reason: recipient[2],
                    });
                }
            });
        });
},
```

Is there a way to make **by default the checkbox not checked** for the customer here?

Is that correct?

1. modify _message_add_suggested_recipient (in `crm_lead.py`) to
   contain "checked" = False for the partner.
2. modify message_get_suggested_recipients (in `chatter.js`) to take checked
   value from parameter `recipient` instead of making `true` by default
   (`checked: true`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in your module at `/static/src/xml/chatter.xml` with following content:

```xml
<templates>
    <t t-name="mail.chatter.ChatComposer" t-extend="mail.chatter.ChatComposer">
        <t
            t-jquery="input[type='checkbox'][t-att-data-fullname='recipient.full_name']"
            t-operation="replace">
            <input type="checkbox" t-att-data-fullname="recipient.full_name" />
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

And then call this file in your manifest:

```py
{
    # name, author, ...
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/chatter.xml'
    ],
}
```

Attention: That will change the behaviour in all chatters in Odoo. It was tested for v10 only.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm! :) Meanwhile I tried different approach (https://stackoverflow.com/q/49875355/1737819) but without success. So used your solution . Thank you again!:-)

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49853643/1737819) provided by Mr. CZoellner. Thank you!:)

I have come up with a solution: just don't know how to package it as a an addon.

See lines that are commented they are changed.

Change `addons/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js`

```js
message_get_suggested_recipients: function () {
    var self = this;
    var email_addresses = _.pluck(this.suggested_partners, 'email_address');
    return this.thread_dataset
        .call('message_get_suggested_recipients', [[this.context.default_res_id], this.context])
        .done(function (suggested_recipients) {
            var thread_recipients = suggested_recipients[self.context.default_res_id];
            _.each(thread_recipients, function (recipient) {
                var parsed_email = utils.parse_email(recipient[1]);
                if (_.indexOf(email_addresses, parsed_email[1]) === -1) {
                    self.suggested_partners.push({
                        //checked: true,
                        checked: recipient[3] || true,
                        partner_id: recipient[0],
                        full_name: recipient[1],
                        name: parsed_email[0],
                        email_address: parsed_email[1],
                        reason: recipient[2],
                    });
                }
            });
        });
},
```

2. And change this file `addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py`

```py
@api.multi
def _message_add_suggested_recipient(self, result, partner=None, email=None, reason=''):
    """ Called by message_get_suggested_recipients, to add a suggested
        recipient in the result dictionary. The form is :
            partner_id, partner_name<partner_email> or partner_name, reason """
    self.ensure_one()
    if email and not partner:
        # get partner info from email
        partner_info = self.message_partner_info_from_emails([email])[0]
        if partner_info.get('partner_id'):
            partner = self.env['res.partner'].sudo().browse([partner_info['partner_id']])[0]
    if email and email in [val[1] for val in result[self.ids[0]]]:  # already existing email -> skip
        return result
    if partner and partner in self.message_partner_ids:  # recipient already in the followers -> skip
        return result
    if partner and partner.id in [val[0] for val in result[self.ids[0]]]:  # already existing partner ID -> skip
        return result
    if partner and partner.email:  # complete profile: id, name <email>
        #result[self.ids[0]].append((partner.id, '%s<%s>' % (partner.name, partner.email), reason))
        result[self.ids[0]].append((partner.id, '%s<%s>' % (partner.name, partner.email), reason, False))
    elif partner:  # incomplete profile: id, name
        result[self.ids[0]].append((partner.id, '%s' % (partner.name), reason))
    else:  # unknown partner, we are probably managing an email address
        result[self.ids[0]].append((False, email, reason))
    return result
```

**And that worked!**

To make this as a an addon in Odoo I created addon with following contents:

**manifest**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
   ...omitted for brewity...
    'depends': ['base','crm','mail'],

    'data': [
        'views/chatter.xml'
    ]
   ...omitted for brewity...
}
```

static/src/js/chatter.js

```
odoo.define('addon1.chatter', function(require){
    'use strict';

    var composer = require('mail.composer');

    composer.BasicComposer.include({
        message_get_suggested_recipients: function () {
        var self = this;
        var email_addresses = _.pluck(this.suggested_partners, 'email_address');
        return this.thread_dataset
            .call('message_get_suggested_recipients', [[this.context.default_res_id], this.context])
            .done(function (suggested_recipients) {
                var thread_recipients = suggested_recipients[self.context.default_res_id];
                _.each(thread_recipients, function (recipient) {
                    var parsed_email = utils.parse_email(recipient[1]);
                    if (_.indexOf(email_addresses, parsed_email[1]) === -1) {
                        self.suggested_partners.push({
                            checked: recipient[3] || true,
                            partner_id: recipient[0],
                            full_name: recipient[1],
                            name: parsed_email[0],
                            email_address: parsed_email[1],
                            reason: recipient[2],
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

views/chatter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="addon1" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/addon1/static/src/js/chatter.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>    
    </data>
</odoo>
```

models/models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-       
from odoo import models, fields, api, tools
from odoo.addons.mail.models.mail_thread import MailThread

class addon1(models.AbstractModel):
    _inherit = 'mail.thread'

    @api.multi
    def _message_add_suggested_recipient(self, result, partner=None, email=None, reason=''):
        result = super(MailThread, self)._message_add_suggested_recipient(self, result, partner, email, reason)

        if partner and partner.email:  # complete profile: id, name <email>
            result[self.ids[0]].append((partner.id, '%s<%s>' % (partner.name, partner.email), reason, False))
        return result
```

After this addon is installed I can observe that javascript (from addon) loads when Odoo website is open, but breakpoints don't catch the right place (when issuing "New message"), that means loaded javascript was ineffective.

***What is wrong?***