# Odoo change base javascript method

Tags: javascript, class, odoo, odoo-10

There is a file in Odoo: [addons/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js#L100) . It contains a method I would like to change: [message_get_suggested_recipients](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js#L100).

For this I created an addon with files:

chatter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <!--template id="assets_backend" name="addon1" inherit_id="web.assets_backend"-->
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/addon1/static/src/js/chatter.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

and

chatter.js

```
odoo.define('addon1.chatter', function(require){
'use strict';

var OdooChatter = require('mail.Chatter');

OdooChatter.include({
    message_get_suggested_recipients: function () {
    var self = this;
    var email_addresses = _.pluck(this.suggested_partners, 'email_address');
    return this.thread_dataset
        .call('message_get_suggested_recipients', [[this.context.default_res_id], this.context])
        .done(function (suggested_recipients) {
            var thread_recipients = suggested_recipients[self.context.default_res_id];
            _.each(thread_recipients, function (recipient) {
                var parsed_email = utils.parse_email(recipient[1]);
                if (_.indexOf(email_addresses, parsed_email[1]) === -1) {
                    self.suggested_partners.push({
                        checked: recipient[3] || true,
                        partner_id: recipient[0],
                        full_name: recipient[1],
                        name: parsed_email[0],
                        email_address: parsed_email[1],
                        reason: recipient[2],
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
});
```

I can see that javascript loads when Odoo website is open, but breakpoints don't catch the right place, that means loaded javascript was ineffective.

**How to change the method because my provided method isn't called (instead the original is called)?**

Answer (score 1):

Modify your chatter.xml file as:

```xml
<template id="your_module.assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" name="Your custome name">
    <xpath expr="//script[@src='/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js']" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/addon1/static/src/js/chatter.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

This works in my case on Odoo 11. In your case (Odoo 10) it should work as well.

---

After re-looking at the Odoo's source code, because you'd like to override the `message_get_suggested_recipients` which is a prop of `mail.composer.BasicComposer` (and not `mail.Chatter`) I think your `include` should be:

```
var composer = require('mail.composer');

var ChatterComposer = composer.BasicComposer.include(
    // This goes your work of message_get_suggested_recipients rewrite.
);
```

Comment: Thank you, now I can see that addon1 chatter.js file is loaded after mail chatter.js. However message_get_suggested_recipients from loaded addon1 chatter.js is not executed . Instead base message_get_suggested_recipients gets executed...

Comment: @Willmore, I changed my answer as I think you've `include`d the wrong part.

Comment: Thank you, for the time helping. I appreciate your help. Did as you wrote  `var composer = require('mail.composer');

var ChatterComposer = composer.BasicComposer.include(
    // This goes your work of message_get_suggested_recipients rewrite.
); ` but still the old message_get_suggested_recipients is called. I suspect that this is because chatter is created with `new ChatterComposer(...)` on this line https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/91ca846447628084f5a089e986319ef18581ddf2/addons/mail/static/src/js/chatter.js#L491 . Should your solution work in that case? :-)

Comment: Sr didn't have time for this, but I will dive a bit deeper into this later.